# Adding a css class to specific items of Yii active checkBoxList

Tags: php, yii, checkboxlist

Working with Yii and active checkboxlist.
I know the params. I need to add a flag css class to the items.
This is my code:

```
$form->checkBoxList($model, 'items', $selected, array(
    'class'=>'default_class'
));
```

This code just adds a default_class to every item. But I need a different class for specific items.

Comment: You can use a CSS pseudo class: `.mycheckboxes:checked {...}`

Comment: You're right. I made a wrong question though!

Comment: I am also facing prob like this. Can you tell in this case $selected is what....?

Comment: @NaincyGupta the $selected is the item(s) that you want to be selected. Check the Yii documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@XIII, I had updated my answer

```
$form->checkBoxList($model, 'items', $selected, array(
  'options' => array(
       'value1'=>array('disabled'=>true, 'label'=>'value 1'),
       'value2'=>array('label'=>'value 2', 'class' => 'css-class-defined'),
   ),
));
```

Please read docs about function what you used, or see source code `system.web.helpers.CHtml` line 764

Comment: I don't need the lableOption! This will add a class to all the labels, not the conditioned ones!

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer, there is nothing in the source to suggest this works.. and I just spent an hour trying to implement it.

Comment: @Arth, what version of Yii you use?

Comment: I'm using 1.1.15, but I referred to the [online code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php).. you can see from the foreach on line 1050 that the options array simply isn't treated the way you suggest. It is interpreted as 'value'=>'labelTitle' and any attempt to use 'value'=>array(...) results in each check box being labelled 'Array' as the array is just printed straight out as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Asked the same question in the Yii forum.
Someone helped me with [this solution](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/40024-adding-a-css-class-to-specific-items-of-yii-active-checkboxlist/page__gopid__191592)

```
foreach ($models as $model) {
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . CHtml::activeName($model, 'attribute') . '[]" value="' . $model->valueField . '" ' . condition ? 'class= "your-class" : '' . '/>';
}
```

This is a good lead for now.